# three.js edges and text jagged/blurry on rotation

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm a three.js beginner. Trying to apply an html canvas as texture to plane geometry. Works fine when there is no rotation. When rotated, a) outside edges of the mesh become jagged (edges/lines within the image are fine) and b) text becomes blurry.

What do I have to do to keep outside edges and text crisp?

My texture is power-of-two (128 x 512). Turning antialiasing on doesn't help.

[Here is a screenshot without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcfNa.jpg)

[And here with rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzYG6.jpg).

Code looks like this:

```js
                    var eltTexture = toTexture2(d, this, go.w, go.Res.ow[0]);
                    
                    // map texture to material
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                        { map : eltTexture } );
                    
                    //define sub image of texture to be applied to mesh
                    var cutout = [
                        new THREE.Vector2(0, (128 - go.Res.ow[0])/128),
                        new THREE.Vector2(go.w/512, (128 - go.Res.ow[0])/128),
                        new THREE.Vector2(go.w/512, 1),
                        new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)];                                  

                    // geometry and UV mapping              
                    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry (go.w, go.Res.ow[0]);
                    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];  // initialize
                    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = 
                        [cutout[3], cutout[0], cutout[2]];
                    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = 
                        [cutout[0], cutout[1], cutout[2]];
                    
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    mesh.position.set(d.threeX, d.threeY, d.threeX);
                    mesh.rotation.set(0,0.6,0);                
                    scene.add( mesh );

                });
                
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

```js
            function toTexture2 (d, svgNode, svgWidth, svgHeight){

                // step 1: serialize eltSVG to xml 
                var eltXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgNode);
                eltXML = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset = utf8,' + eltXML;

                // step 2: draw eltXML to image
                var eltImage = document.body.appendChild(
                    document.createElement("img"));
                eltImage.id = "eltImage";
                eltImage.style.display = "none";
                eltImage.width = svgWidth;
                eltImage.height = svgHeight;
                eltImage.src = eltXML; 

                // step 3: draw image to canvas
                // NOTE: define canvas parameters position, width and 
                // height in html, NOT IN CSS, otherwise image
                // will become blurry - don't ask why!
                var eltCanvas = document.body.appendChild(
                    document.createElement("canvas"));
                eltCanvas.id = "eltCanv";
                eltCanvas.style.display = "none";
                eltCanvas.width = 512;
                eltCanvas.height = 128;
 
                // get context
                var ctx = eltCanvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false}); 

                // draw svg element to canvas, not including portrait image
                ctx.drawImage(eltImage, parseInt(0), parseInt(0), 
                    svgWidth, svgHeight); 

                // draw portrait image to canvas
                var portrait = document.getElementById(d.nameConcat + "Img");
                ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;  // opacity of portrait image
                ctx.drawImage(portrait, go.Res.strw[0], go.Res.strw[0], 
                    go.Res.iw[0], go.Res.iw[0]);

                var texture = new THREE.Texture(eltCanvas);
                texture.needsUpdate = true;  
                
                return texture;

            } // function toTexture2
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: this should be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387747/threejs-texture-is-pixelated-when-seen-from-distance. The only way to get jagged edges is to comment out `antialias: true` from the `renderer`. Are you using a WebGL renderer?

Comment: @gaitat: Antialias on renderer takes care of edges, great, thanks! (I had tried antialias on ctx.....). Yes, using WebGL renderer. Looked at the link. There are several differences to my code - which ones might help for crisper text? I already have power-of-two canvas - but should I set this up differently?

Comment: @gaitat: just tried texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy(). this improves text a little bit. can it be improved further?

Comment: one other thing would be to set `.generateMipmaps = false` on your texture.

Comment: @gaitat: thanks! tried this....                var texture = new THREE.Texture(eltCanvas);
                texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
                texture.generateMipmaps = false;
                texture.needsUpdate = true; ....but then the images don't render anymore (just see black rectangles).

Comment: @gaitat: what would be the reason for .generateMipmaps = false? As I understood it, the aim was to make the texture power-of-two so that mipmaps could be generated?

Comment: powers of two on textures is a hardware limitation/feature; nothing to do with mipmaps. But the way mipmaps work is to blur the image as the camera moves far away. You want your images with constant quality.

Comment: @gaitat: aha! will try to get it to render with this setting and come back once more if still not crisp. many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's been a long time since you've posted this, I have the solution in case anyone else is experiencing the same issue.

Add this to your renderer:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
```